# node js express route all paths

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I am using express. I like to create a route that navigates all requests of type "get" with url prefix '/app/static/*pagePath' to "/assets/app/static/pagePath".
I am trying to do the following, but is doesn't work.

```
app.get('/app/static/*path', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile('assets/app/static/' + req.params.path);
});
```

Any idea?

Comment: Are you meaning to use `:path`?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: If the user will go to app/static/a/b/c.html and the route is /app/static/:path, will path be equal to "a/b/c.html"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a middleware with a prefix and some short-circuit logic:

```
app.use('/app/static', function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.method !== 'get') {
    next();
    return;
  }
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/assets' + req.path);
});
```

(this is untested so might not be 100% ready to go, but you get the idea)

Actually, looking again at your question, are you sure this can't be handled by the `express.static` middleware just given the proper root directory?

```
app.use('/app/static', express.static(__dirname + '/assets'));
```

Comment: Yes, you can have however many you want, just have additional `app.use` calls.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to include subdirectories, you can do it using a regex; this regex will match any directory/file structure under `/app/static/`

```
app.get(/^\/app\/static\/(.*)/, function (req, res) {
    console.log('assets/app/static/' + req.params[0]);
    res.sendfile('assets/app/static/' + req.params[0]);
});
```

As to your question about multiple static directories, yes, you can. Just `app.use` both;

```
app.use("/static", express.static(__dirname + "/assets"));
app.use("/static", express.static(__dirname + "/alternate_assets"));
```

The file will be served from the first directory where it's found (searching `/assets` first, then `/alternate_assets`), but to make things less confusing, you may want to avoid having the same file name in both directories.

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers had worked for me in the past because they were missing two small details:

- `app.use` calls to define static directories
- These definitions need to happen *before* you send the HTML file

Like this:

```
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/static'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) { 
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html'); 
});
```

And then you can include them in directly in your HTML (or SVG, etc.) like this:

• `<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/index.css">`

• `<image x="0" y="0" xlink:href="static/picture.svg" />`

• etc.

Comment: dont do that! middlewares can't be inicialized at each requests...

Comment: @UrielAlves Nice catch, I wrote this in 2014. I agree with you here, and moved it out of the handler... but for the record, you can dynamically add middleware to the stack later in run-time. A use case might be requiring some user request to occur before defining an API.

Answer (score 0):

GET /app/static/foo/bar/buz ---> req.path === /app/static/foo/bar/buz so:

```
app.get('/app/static/:path*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile('assets' + req.path);
});
```